# How to get the text at mouse location (without click&drag and select) outside my application?

Tags: objective-c

I'm writting a APP to translate the text at the mouse location (just mouse over, not clicked & dragged to select) outside the APP, but I don't know how to get this text without selecting it .

This is a MAC OSx application